# Getting latest Subsonic builds

Tags: .net, orm, subsonic

I need the latest Subsonic build or build it by my own. [Subsonic project web site](http://www.subsonicproject.com/) shows the latest available version is [Subsonic v3.0.0.3](http://blog.wekeroad.com/subsonic/subsonic-3-0-0-3-is-released/) released at July 15, 2009.

Questions:

- Are there any later builds - e.g. maintained by community members? If so, how can I get the latest one?
- In worst case I'm ready to get the latest source code and try to build it by my own. Are there any instructions for this?

Please note, that I'm not interested in almost 1 year old builds - I need a build based on the latest code for tests (LINQ, performance), ideally - compiled for .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a newer build from 2010-03-21 here: http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/downloads

But it's fairly easy pull the code from [here](http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0.git)

Open the solution in Visual Studio, build it and you should be fine.